# PL/SQL: REGEXP REPLACE with dot and pattern

Tags: regex, plsql

I am trying to replace the string using regexp_replace in PLSQL and not getting desired output. i am new to this. please advise where i am going wrong.

```
names := 'table_200_file1_record1.column1   table_200_file2_record2.column2'
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(names,'([table_200]*[.]*){1,}','') FROM DUAL;
```

Desired output: (i want to remove everything before . operator which is starting with table_200)

```
column1 column2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace everything that's not a dot after table_200, up to the first dot you find, i.e.:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('table_200_file1_record1.column1   table_200_file2_record2.column2','table_200[^\.]+(\.)','') FROM DUAL
```